# Save old activity data android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

Two activities A,B.
When A starts data is defined. From A to B activity is called, 
And A activity is finally destroy.
How can i stop destroying A activity ?
And get the same oncreate data when came back from B.

Comment: This is pretty much against the android philosophy. Why do you want the activity not to be destroyed? Perhaps you can think of fragments to create different frames within the activity (and transition between them). If you do not want to destroy the activity for data persistence, look at the data storage methods that android offers and retrieve them in the onResume

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intent for navigation from A to B. Don't call finish() method. Just start your B Activity.

**for ex :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent (A.this,B.class);
startActivity(intent);
//Here dont use finish() method as it destroys current Activity.
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: If @OnkarNene is right, then you'll probably want to save all your data when `onSaveInstanceState`, so you can retrieve them in `onCreate`, in the case that system decides to destroy your activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to ActivityA to ActivityB then ActivityA is not destroy by default. if you give finish() method than and than only ActivityA will destroy.Otherwise ActivityA is only stop but still into background state.So,do not add finish() method when you transfer from one activity to another activity.

What you can do for your situation

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And When you can back to ActivityA it will call onStop() method of ActivityA.
So, you can define your date in onStop() method again.